# Extra field from Firebase Document snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

For some odd reason I am receiving document snapshots from Firebase that include extra fields defining other fields. The following is a sample `JSON` from a `DocumentSnapshot`:

```
{
"_fieldsProto": {
    "general_knowledge": {
        "mapValue": {
            "fields": {
                "“What do ya mean?”": {
                    "booleanValue": false,
                    "valueType": "booleanValue"
                },
                "question": {
                    "stringValue": "In the TV show friends, what is Joey Tribbiani’s famous line?",
                    "valueType": "stringValue"
                },
                "“How you doin’?”": {
                    "booleanValue": true,
                    "valueType": "booleanValue"
                },
                "“Who’s home?”": {
                    "booleanValue": false,
                    "valueType": "booleanValue"
                }
            }
        },
        "valueType": "mapValue"
    },
    "science": {
        "mapValue": {
            "fields": {
                "question": {
                    "stringValue": "Who is considered the “father” of organic chemistry?",
                    "valueType": "stringValue"
                },
                "Charles Darwin": {
                    "booleanValue": false,
                    "valueType": "booleanValue"
                },
                "Gregor Mendel": {
                    "booleanValue": false,
                    "valueType": "booleanValue"
                },
                "Friedrich Wohler": {
                    "booleanValue": true,
                    "valueType": "booleanValue"
                }
            }
        },
        "valueType": "mapValue"
    },
    "music": {
        "mapValue": {
            "fields": {
                "question": {
                    "stringValue": "Who released the 2018 album “Graffiti U”?",
                    "valueType": "stringValue"
                },
                "Adam Levine": {
                    "booleanValue": false,
                    "valueType": "booleanValue"
                },
                "Keith Urban": {
                    "booleanValue": true,
                    "valueType": "booleanValue"
                },
                "John Legend": {
                    "booleanValue": false,
                    "valueType": "booleanValue"
                }
            }
        },
        "valueType": "mapValue"
    },
    "history": {
        "mapValue": {
            "fields": {
                "question": {
                    "stringValue": "The Incan Empire is located in which modern-day country?",
                    "valueType": "stringValue"
                },
                "Peru": {
                    "booleanValue": true,
                    "valueType": "booleanValue"
                },
                "The United States of America": {
                    "booleanValue": false,
                    "valueType": "booleanValue"
                },
                "New Zealand": {
                    "booleanValue": false,
                    "valueType": "booleanValue"
                }
            }
        },
        "valueType": "mapValue"
    }
},
"_ref": {
    "_firestore": {
        "projectId": "trivia-that-pays"
    },
    "_path": {
        "segments": ["daily_play_questions", "000086"]
    },
    "_converter": {}
},
"_serializer": {
    "allowUndefined": false
},
"_readTime": {
    "_seconds": 1625961162,
    "_nanoseconds": 980162000
},
    "_createTime": {
        "_seconds": 1611029311,
        "_nanoseconds": 23101000
    },
    "_updateTime": {
        "_seconds": 1611200786,
        "_nanoseconds": 3550000
    }
}
```

Field such as `_fieldProto`, `booleanValue`, `valueType`, `mapValue`, `fields`, `_ref`, `_serializer`, `_readTime`, `_createTime`, `_updateTime` never existed before. The following is the JSON I used to get:

```
{
"general_knowledge": {
    "“What do ya mean?”": "false",
    "question": "In the TV show friends, what is Joey Tribbiani’s famous line?",
    "“How you doin’?”": "true",
    "“Who’s home?”": "false"
},
"science": {
    "question": "Who is considered the “father” of organic chemistry?",
    "Charles Darwin": "false",
    "Gregor Mendel": "false",
    "Friedrich Wohler": "true"
},
"music": {
    "question": "Who released the 2018 album “Graffiti U”?",
    "Adam Levine": "false",
    "Keith Urban": "true",
    "John Legend": "false"
},
"history": {
    "question": "The Incan Empire is located in which modern-day country?",
    "Peru": "true",
    "The United States of America": "false",
    "New Zealand": "false"
}
}
```

I am receiving this data by using Firebase Functions. Here is the code I am using to get the data.

```
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.func = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    const dailyQuestionBankRef = db
              .collection("daily_play_questions"); // set collection reference

    const selectedQuestionSet = await dailyQuestionBankRef
              .doc(randomNumber)
              .get();

    res.status(200).send(selectedQuestionSet.data());
});
```

randomNumber is just a number randomly generated to specify the document. There is more code in between, but is most likely tied to how the randomNumber is generated. So the problem is with the data that I get. Is this something have to do with the method I am using to get the data or am I setting something up incorrectly? The way I used to get the data, is the way my database is setup in Firebase. I don't understand what the extra fields have to do with anything.

Comment: That object seems to be a DocumentSnapshot but I'm not sure why it's being returned from the function. Have you tried logging `selectedQuestionSet.data()` in the cloud function itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed your function is not `async` but you are trying to use `await`. I wonder how your function ran at first place. But please try the following:

```
export const getData = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const dailyQuestionBankRef = admin.firestore().collection("tests"); // set collection reference

    return dailyQuestionBankRef.doc("Test1").get().then((selectedQuestionSet) => {
        return res.status(200).send(selectedQuestionSet.data());
    });
})
```

Alternatively you can just make the function `async` like this:

```
export const getData = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const dailyQuestionBankRef = admin.firestore().collection("tests"); // set collection reference

  const selectedQuestionSet = await dailyQuestionBankRef.doc("Test1").get()
  return res.status(200).send(selectedQuestionSet.data());
})
```

Comment: I am marking your answer as correct, because I guess that was the answer.  But this is what happened:

After adding 'async' it gave me a different error. Kind of saying that no response was given when I tried to get the json in the web, but the firebase functions log game me "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received function data ". Then for some reason later on it gave me the right data. Idk maybe it was my error somewhere in the link.

Comment: Thanks @ElonasMarcauskas. You need to click the tick icon to accept the answer;)

Comment: I went the extra mile and removed the 'async'. It gave me the results as I expected, the correct results. Then added the 'async' back again, it still works. So I will keep an eye out for this and report if something happens again. @Dharmaraj thank you for the help.

Comment: Yeah. I missed that. Got too excited about the fix to my problem :). Should be good now.